CPU wait time on Linux system
I want to measure the CPU "starvation" of the Linux host and I'm trying to find a way to measure it. It seems that one of the ways to measure it is to read the procs_running field value from the /proc/stat file. And if this value is more than CPUs online that means that the system has more tasks ready to run than have CPUs to run them.
However, if I poll this value from the /proc/stat file for example, once a second, I can miss moments when procs_running was higher than the number of CPUs and thus miss events when the system was not been able to run task due to shortage of the CPU resources.
Is there any way to reliably monitor such events in a Linux system?

Yes, you can use /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpuidle/stateY/time  (for appropriate X and Y, see cpuidle, state0 may be the active state, check the doc) and divide the sum (for each CPU) by the uptime (after appropriate unit conversion). Note that counting the CPU vs the number of processes won't get you anything: you can have a single CPU and one thousand processes, all waiting for IO and that CPU would still be idle.

I need CPU "starvation" metric, not utilization. For example, if I have system with one CPU and during one second I had 2 tasks that were in "runnable" or "running" states I want to know that during this second I had 1 task running and 1 task waiting.

Isn't this essentially what the load average measures?

Then you need /proc/schedstats?

Load average is close enough, but I need to scrap this value each second so it will not help me. Anyway, PSI is just exactly what I want.

You might want the Pressure Stall Information "some CPU" statistic.  It's designed to answer a question that's at least similar to what you're looking for.
"How often did a CPU (i.e. a hardware thread) have two or more tasks ready to run?"
https://lwn.net/Articles/753840/
If it's built into your kernel you'll have a /proc/pressure directory.  There's some documentation here and "Pressure Stall Information" is fairly Googleable
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/psi.html
